# Deprecation warning: can't load Heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

My Rails app is using version 3.2.3 and I want to deploy to Heroku for test (cross browser). I have never had a problem before but now I get the "Sorry something went wrong" message as I try and load my page.

I get this error message in the terminal after running `heroku run rake db:migrate`:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support   for     these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your   Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from  at /app/config/environment.rb:5)

When I look in my plugins folder there is just an empty gitkeep file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, it was a rookie error. I had to set

```
 config.assets.compress = true
```

"true" being the important part.

Answer (score 3):

This is only a warning, which can't cause a exception/500 error ("Sorry something went wrong"). 
Check the log via `heroku logs`, something else is causing this exception and you should be able to see it in there.